# Find index of last occurrence of a character from character-set in string

Tags: swift, string, find, swift5

Is there a short way to find the index of the last character in a string that belongs to a given character set?

So with a string `"abcd123gws"` and character set `"1234567890"`, the result should be 6: the digit `3`.

Comment: Hi perhaps get all the matches using `NSRegularExpression` and then pick the last one. The character set could be a regular expression like `[0-9]` or `[abcde]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
let input = "abcd123gws"
let characters = Set("1234567890")

if let lastOccurrenceIndex = input.lastIndex(where: characters.contains) {
    let result = input.distance(from: input.startIndex, to: lastOccurrenceIndex)
    print(result) // 6
}
```

---

As @LeoDabus suggested in the comments, if your character set contains of numbers only, you can use `\.isWholeNumber` (no need for a separate `Set`):

```
if let lastOccurrenceIndex = input.lastIndex(where: \.isWholeNumber) { ... }
```

Comment: `lastIndex(where: characters.contains)` or even better using KeyPath Character property `isWholeNumber` >  `lastIndex(where: \.isWholeNumber)`

Comment: If OP intent is to get the index value as Int it might be better to search the index of an array of characters. `Array(input).lastIndex(where: characters.contains)` or `Array(input).lastIndex(where: \.isWholeNumber)`

Comment: No, my character set does not contain numbers only. You solution works! Thanks.